# How to create triangle-shaped list using list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What would be the easiest way to create a list in the following format:

```
[[0],
 [0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0],
 [0]]
```

This would be for n=3, so the question is mostly how to reverse the iterating variable that denotes the amount of elements per list.

The following list comprehension for example:

```
[[0]*(i+1) for i in range(3)]
```

Would create:

```
[[0],
 [0,0],
 [0,0,0]]
```

Is there a nifty way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a nifty way using the `abs` function:

```py
>>> n = 3
>>> [[0] * (n - abs(n - i)) for i in range(1, 2*n)]
[[0],
 [0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0],
 [0]]
```

Comment: Similar: `[[0] * min(i, n*2 - i) for i in range(1, n*2)]`

Answer (score 5):

A nifty way is

```
[[0]*(i+1) for i in range(3)] + [[0]*(i+1) for i in range(2)][::-1]
```

i.e. doing the same thing twice, but with one less row, then flipping it around with a reverse slice `[::-1]`.

And to package this into a neat pair of functions,

```
def half_triangle(n):
   return [[0]*(i+1) for i in range(n)]

def triangle(n):
   return half_triangle(n) + half_triangle(n - 1)[::-1]
```

```
>>> pprint(triangle(5))
[[0],
 [0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0],
 [0]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

One simple way would be to put an inline `if` operator in
the left-side expression of your list-comprehension, to 
transform the  `i` delivered by the `for` part on the 
`side` you want:

```
[[0]*((i+1) if i < 3 else (5 - i)) for i in range(5)]
```

However, this is hard to read and error prone, due
to having to think about the various "+1" and "-1" 
involved, and having to hardcode the maximum
size in three different points. Having to type a number
depending on your desired size in three places is
solvable with a variable, tough:

```py
max_size = 10
[[0]*((i+1) if i < max_size else (max_size * 2 - 1  - i)) for i in range(max_size * 2 - 1)]
```

And with max_size = 10:

```
Out[6]: 
[[0],
 [0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0],
 [0]]
```

However, this solution does nothing to let the code more readable, 
or easier to deal with the "+1" and "-1" for the edgecases.

A cleaner and more idiomatic solution is to use an
specialized **"generator"**:

`range` in Python is a special builtin that returns an object
that is "iterable". 
If you as simply as create anofo ther "iterable" that will return the
sizes you want, you just plug it in place of the `range` inside your expression.

In Python, one of the easiest way of creating an iterable is creating a "generator function". Which is simply a function that instead of using `return`, uses the `yield` keyword to supply partial results to another context - in this example, the `for` statement inside the comprehension.

And since we are writing a function body, then the easiest and more readable way to create the triangle pattern is to have a `for` that will increase the size, and another `for` that will decrease the size after that one - both of these make plain use of the "range" to get a linear pattern:

In code, that is just:

```py
def triangle(max_size):
    for i in range(1, max_size + 1):
        yield i
    for i in range(max_size - 1, 0, -1):
        yield i
```

And then you use `triangle` instead of `range` for super-easy-to-read-and-maintain code:

```
In [8]: [[0] * i for i in triangle(10)]                                                                                                                                             
Out[8]: 
[[0],
 [0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0],
 [0]]
```

Comment: The brackets in `(i+1) if i < 3 else (5 - i)` aren't necessary; you can make it a bit easier to read by removing them.

Comment: we clarly diverge on what is "easier to read" them. Shorter? yes. Easier to read? Questionable. A good argument for that is that removing those extra brackets would actually break the code, since the `[0] * ` terms would be bound to the `true` side of the `if`, yielding `[[0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0], 2, 1]`

Comment: You still need brackets *around* that expression, obviously.

Comment: ah - the inner brackets. I still find then more readable, for the same reason - the computer can find easier what is bound to the `if ... else`  than a human looking at the code - and readability counts.

Comment: Well, if brackets around `i < 3` don't improve readability then I don't see why brackets around the other two parts would help; but sure, that's a matter of opinion. That said, you can also change `range(max_size * 2 - 1)` to `range(1, max_size * 2)` then the expression becomes `i if i < max_size else (2 * max_size - i)`, which doesn't need the off-by-one fixes.

Comment: becasue thouse are surrounded by `if` and `else`?  Anyway, as I said, that is the "hard to maintain and not recommended" solution.

Comment: @kaya3: hoping this will make you feel better: you are right. sorry about the fuzz. I won't change it in the answer above right now, but I noticed in "real code" I do not actually usually include those extra brackets.

Comment: Oh, it's not about me feeling good or bad, I just wanted to make a suggestion and back it up with my reasoning. I acknowledged it's a matter of opinion, and I think the answer doesn't need to be changed if you think it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reversed()` to reverse a range. So, for a maximum length `n`, you can use:

```
[[0]*(i+1) for i in list(range(n))+list(reversed(range(n-1)))]
```